# Replacing one namespace with another

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces

In the below input XML I am getting `ns1` and `ns2` prefixes.
In the output the namespace `ns1` should be replaced with **dh** and the namespace `ns2` should be replaced with **sk**.

Can anyone please help on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<sh:sampleDocument schemaVersion="" creationDate=""xmlns:sh="htpp://sample1.com">
    <sampleHeader>
        <ns1:sampledocumentheader xmlns:ns1="htpp://sample2.com">
            <ns1:HeaderVersion />                
            <ns1:ContactInformation>
                <ns1:Contact />                    
                <ns1:EmailAddress />                    
                <ns1:FaxNumber />                    
                <ns1:TelephoneNumber />                    
                <ns1:ContactTypeIdentifier />                    
            </ns1:ContactInformation>
        </ns1:sampledocumentheader>
    </sampleHeader>
    <sampleBody>
        <sampleList>
            <sampleEvent>
                <Time />                    
                <action />                    
                <ns2:sampleExtension xmlns:ns2="htpp://sample3.com">
                    <ns2:Value />                        
                    <ns2:Number />                        
                </ns2:sampleExtension>
            </sampleEvent>
        </sampleList>
    </sampleBody>
</sh:sampleDocument>
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing that? The prefix carries no meaning whatsoever and can be completely arbitrary; what really matters is the URI it's bound to.

Comment: the receiver application needs those prefixes to accept the data. I have discussed with them also but they want those prefixes.

Comment: So they are too lazy to do it right, and as a result you have extra work to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to do this. The choice of a namespace prefix is completely arbitrary. If the target application requires a specific prefix to be used, then it's the target application that needs to be fixed, not your XML.

Anyway, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="htpp://sample2.com"
xmlns:ns2="htpp://sample3.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 ns2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:*">
    <xsl:element name="dh:{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns2:*">
    <xsl:element name="sk:{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```